# Space arround ripple effect in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I am currently trying to create a layout which looks like the default Google Calculator in the latest Android. Now I am struggling with the GridLayout and a custom component (called `FlatButton`).
The .java-code of the `FlatButton`

```
public class FlatButton extends android.widget.FrameLayout {
...
public FlatButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    // Load attributes
    final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs, R.styleable.FlatButton, defStyle, 0);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(  
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_flat_button, this);
    setTextColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.FlatButton_textColor, getTextColor()));
    setText(a.getText(R.styleable.FlatButton_text));

    this.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    a.recycle();
    this.setClickable(true);
}
```

The .xml content of `control_flat_button`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/flat_button_width"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/flat_button_width"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/flat_button_width"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/flat_button_width"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

These buttons or now used in a `GridLayout`. I want to fill the entire space of the Layout with these buttons, whereby eatch row should contain 5 of them. My current approach uses the entire space, but there is something strange. The red-colored `background` for example is correctly set across the entire button, but when I click on one of them, the ripple effect seems to have some kind of invisble border in the button as you can see in the right button below:
[image].
I am using this .xml layout to show them:

```
 <GridLayout
        android:useDefaultMargins="false"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        >

    <com.flashtek.playground.FlatButton
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:text="Button"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            />
    <com.flashtek.playground.FlatButton
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:text="Button"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            />
        ...and some more buttons...
</GridLayout>
```

How can I get rid of this border for the ripple effect? This seems to be connected to the `GridLayout` because when I use the `FlatButton` in a simple `LinearLayout` this problem does no occur. So, what am I doing wrong?